# Rails Multi-level nasted attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

I want to create an event where:
- event has multiple schedules
- each schedule has one address

I use cocoon for the multiple events, however, when I use the form:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :address do |address| 
  = render 'address_field', :f => address
```

It will display when my stored events has address, but if I trying to create one, I have to make it:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :address_attributes do |address| 
  = render 'address_field', :f => address
```

but that means I can never see my address details in the form

How can solve this?

Comment: I think you can do something like `unless schedule.address.exists? schedule.build_address end` in your controller so that you can use `f.simple_fields_for :address do |address|` for both cases.  Have you tried that?  Also could you post your `new` and `edit` actions?